# Media Query: Doesn't Change Style when i resize the browser

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have this code . When i resize the browser to `min-width: 480px` it doesn't change the background color to blue and width to 100px

this is my code so far:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .boxcontainer {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100px;
    }
}
.boxcontainer{
        width: 1300px;
        background-color: green;
        height: 200px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="boxcontainer">
  
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the order of the CSS rule, Change your CSS into

```
.boxcontainer {
    width: 1300px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 200px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .boxcontainer {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

As in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/o9jfx5pa/) example. the background is blue as long as the width is not less than `480px`, otherwise it turns green.

IF by any chance you meant to do the opposite, *because `.boxcontainer{width:1300px}` makes me think you want that* , then just change the media query break point to `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)` instead of `@media screen and (min-width: 480px)`.

You can see the second option in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/zfgszjk8/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Mi-Creativity didn't know that rule :)